# Unable to finish testing ColdFusion 11 website which was migrated from ColdFusion 9 due to CFIDE\scripts

Tags: coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

My team recently made the migration from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11. We are currently in the testing phase. During our testing we discovered there were numerous drop down lists were not being populated.  Those list are populated from the selection of other lists.

At first we looked into cfselect, but discovered that wasn't the issue as we dug deeper we discovered that scripts(cfform.js, cfmessage.js, cfajax.js, cf.css and several others) we leverage for functionality were no longer accessible due to the CFIDE lockdown. After doing some research online we ended up doing the following with the help of our WebOps team.

1. Create a folder in D:\CF11\cfusion\wwwroot\ called  cfM_scripts
2. Move the scripts folder from CFIDE and paste into cfM_scripts
3. In IIS right clicked on the website devtest.mysite.com and select add virtual directory
4. Name the alias /cfM_scripts
5. In CF administrator Settings, "Default ScriptSrc Directory" set to /cfM_scripts/scripts
6. Point the virtual directory to D:\CF11\cfusion\wwwroot\cfM_scripts\scripts\

Despite one of our System Admins doing the following, we are still stuck with the same problem. Now I know best practices state not to use those built in script files however we just want to test and get the site to work properly first before we start any major changes.

Was this done correctly? If not what did we miss? Is there another workaround to gain access to those files.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy should be good.

You might want to check a couple of things in your test environment.

Add the CFIDE virtual directory to the site (remove the global scripts value from cfadmin) the way it used to be on CF9 and verify that everything does work.  This will guarantee that the missing CFIDE virtual directory is really the problem.

Try adding the scriptSrc attribute to a <cfform> tag and see if that works.

If the missing CFIDE virtual directory is the problem, you may want to consider implementing a solution like this instead.

1. Copy the full CFIDE folder {cfusionroot}\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE to a new folder.  It can be outside of the {cfusionroot} folder structure.
2. Remove all of the 'unsecure' folders from the new CFIDE folder leaving basically the scripts folder.
3. Add this new safe folder as your CFIDE virtual directory.

Using this solution will avoid having to go to change your cfadmin setting or all of your <cfform> tags and setting the scriptSrc attribute because the CFIDE virtual directory exists with the /cfide/scripts folder.

This should be safe because /cfide/adminapi, /cfide/administrator, etc. will be gone from your copy of the CFIDE virtual directory.

Use the F12 network traffic option on a browser to make sure that the status of all requests is 200 (success).  The script request should be there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this now and will report back by noon today. I figure I was close, but things were still not working. Just hope this doesn't piss off our WebOps team(system admins) . Me and him have been doing the back and forth on this for several days.

Comment: I looked over your response again, how different is your suggestion compared to mine?  Just asking, before I go telling our system admin guy to start changing stuff.

Comment: The primary difference is that my method will keep the /CFIDE virtual directory name so that CF will not need to change.  Your method should work as well although I wouldn't 'move' the scripts folder in #2 of your method.  I usually leave the /CFIDE virtual directory intact and use cfadmin//IIS to restrict which IP addresses can access the admin/adminapi folders.  But then I have full access to the web server as an admin and it sounds like that might not be your situation.

Comment: So just to verify, because I have to be clear when I speak to our System Admins...

    1. Copy and Paste the CFIDE folder and place it somewhere else, that's not D:\CF11\cfusion\wwwroot\  
    2. Then in IIS right clicked on the website devtest.mysite.com and select add virtual directory
    Name the alias /CFIDE or /CFIDE/scripts (not sure which one)
    3. In CF administrator Settings, "Default ScriptSrc Directory" set to /CFIDE/scripts (I believe it was orignally this)
    4. Point the virtual directory to D:\SomewhereElse\CFIDE\scripts\

Comment: 2. /CFIDE.  4. has already been done in step 2.  You'll also need a step where the administrator, adminapi, etc. folders are removed from your copy.